# How to remove character from left of the string until first : if found?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have JSON String as the one below which is returned from the previous function. It is a string, not object.

```
{
    "qs1": {
        "mistake": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Subject-Verb Agreement Errors."
        }, {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Sentence Fragments."
        }, {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Missing Comma After Introductory Element."
        }]
    }
}
```

I converted it into an object by using `Jquery.parseJSON()` now I want to use length to find a number of mistakes.

**Problem:**
the first key `qs1` of the returned JSON can be different like qs2,qs3 & so on. I don't want to use a loop to get the key name qs1,qs2 because it will take a lot of time in only getting a key name and if I have a lot of questions. Also, I don't know the number of questions.

Is there is any way to check `qs1.mistake.length>0` without knowing the key name(qs1).

Below is my function:

```
function SelectiMstake(value) {
    alert(value);
    var value2 = jQuery.parseJSON(value);
    var NewHtml=""; 

    if(value2.mistake.length>0) {
        alert("mistake found");
        //for(var mistakei = 0; mistakei < value2.mistake.length; mistakei++) {
        //          NewHtml+= "<input type='check' value='"+ value2.mistake[mistakei] +"'>"+ value2.mistake[mistakei] +"<br>";
        //      }
        //$("#DisplayMistakes").html(NewHtml);
    } else {
        alert("No mistakes found in the following Question");
    }
}
```

if there is no way I want to stick with my question part when I get JSON string then I want to remove `{"qs1":` from the start of the string and `}` from the last. Don't use a character to remove from the start otherwise `{"qs12":` this will give the wrong result.

Comment: Just use `Object.values` if you don't care about the key?

Comment: You forgot to prefix with `qs1`. So: `value2.qs1.mistake.length>0`

Comment: @trincot  I don't want to use key name qst1 because it will be different every time. qs2,qs3...qs30. I am looking for an alternative for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), and just select the first element, or loop through the values (Which is now an array), if you want to check each `qs*`:

```js
var json = '{"qs1":{"mistake":[{"id":1,"name":"Subject-Verb Agreement Errors."},{"id":1,"name":"Sentence Fragments."},{"id":1,"name":"Missing Comma After Introductory Element."}]}}';
var parsed = JSON.parse(json);
var vals = Object.values(parsed);

console.log(vals[0]);

console.log(vals[0].mistake.length); // 3
```

Comment: vals[0].mistake.length not worked & also tried vals[0].length.

Comment: @SayedMohdAli `vals[0].mistake.length` works here. I copied your JSON directly, and updated my answer to show that this works.

Comment: yes, worked for me 2, thanks  I can accept answer after 2 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just checked it out the function it is converting an object into an array. This is what I want the index of my key which was not possible when it was an object.

Comment: @SayedMohdAli Definitely check out `Object.keys()`, `Object.values()` and `Object.entries()` for iterating through an object.